# kext loaded but nowhere to be found on disk

Tags: big-sur, kernel-extensions

The following states the problem: a kext with the identifier `aluveitie.RadeonSensor` is loaded but I cannot find the actual file. `kextutil` hints that it used to be at `/Library/Extensions/RadeonSensor.kext`, and indeed I did install that a long while ago, and removed it. The machine has been rebooted many times since then: why does that kext still load? And load from where?

```
~% kmutil showloaded|egrep -i aluveitie                                                                          
No variant specified, falling back to release
   53    0 0                  0x14000    0x14000    aluveitie.RadeonSensor (0.3.3) C05A7C6F-BD34-300A-9139-C53245A18CAA <49 14 9 6 5 3 2 1>

~% kmutil find -b aluveitie.RadeonSensor                                                                         
No variant specified, falling back to release

~% sudo kextutil -bundle-id aluveitie.RadeonSensor                                                               
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load --bundle-identifier aluveitie.RadeonSensor
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Could not find: Extension 'aluveitie.RadeonSensor' not found at: /Library/Extensions/RadeonSensor.kext" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find: Extension 'aluveitie.RadeonSensor' not found at: /Library/Extensions/RadeonSensor.kext}
```

**Update**

This is on MacOS Big Sur. The file is nowhere to be found. So the only explanation left is that this kext is still in the kernel cache, and that MacOS did not purge it from there for reasons I can't explain. A clue: I found out that unloading it fails:

```
~% sudo kmutil unload -b aluveitie.RadeonSensor                                                          
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload) (-603946984)"
```

Comment: What OS version? The simplest thing would be to do a search, either with something like EasyFind, or in the Terminal, through /Library and /System folders. And also check the user Library, I suppose

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks. I added an update…

Comment: Have you done a Safe Boot? That might clear the kernel extension cache.

Comment: Do you have the `locate` database active? (I'm not sure if it's turned on by default on Big Sur — which I'm using, too; if all else fails, Homebrew to the rescue!) If so, you can always search for `RadeonSensor` (or `aluveitie`) and see what it comes up with. `locate \.kext | egrep \.kext$ | more` could also be used to find _all_ kexts on disk, too...

Answer (score 0):

Might be in /Library/StagedExtensions.

Try if Terminal

```
sudo kmutil clear-staging
```

helps.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not in that directory. I added an update…

Comment: @frapadingue Did you try deleting/rebuilding the kextcache?